# Save value to UserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have just started programming in swift so please take that in consideration. I am working on a app that send sms messages depending on a button clicked. I have everything figured out and the app works fine but I have a problem that the app prompts me to enter the recipient number every time I open the app. I figured out that the phone number is not saving but I can't find a way to save the usrTextField var to UserDefaults. Here is the code of the app:

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI

class ViewController: UIViewController, MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate{
var usrTextField: UITextField?
var pwdTextField: UITextField?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        }

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

    
@IBAction func displayAlertAction(_ sender: Any) {
    
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Enter phone number and password", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alertController.addTextField(configurationHandler: usrTextField)
    alertController.addTextField(configurationHandler: pwdTextField)
    
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: self.okHandler)
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
    
    alertController.addAction(okAction)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
    
    self.present(alertController, animated: true)

    
    
}

func usrTextField(textField: UITextField!) {
    usrTextField = textField
    usrTextField?.placeholder = "06XXXXXXX"
    
    
}

    
func pwdTextField(textField: UITextField!) {
    pwdTextField = textField
    pwdTextField?.placeholder = "123456"
    pwdTextField?.isSecureTextEntry = true
    
            
}
func okHandler(alert: UIAlertAction!) {
    let simpleVC = SimpleVC()
    simpleVC.customInit(usrStr: (usrTextField?.text)!, pwdStr: (pwdTextField?.text)!)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(simpleVC, animated: true)
}

func messageComposeViewController(_ controller: MFMessageComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MessageComposeResult) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
@IBAction func Dugme1(_ sender: AnyObject)
{
    
    if MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText()
    {
        let controller = MFMessageComposeViewController ()
        controller.body = "Message1"
        if let temp = usrTextField {
           
            controller.recipients = [self.usrTextField!.text!]
            
        } else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "AlfaPro Alarm", message: "Please enter the phone number in settings", preferredStyle: .alert)

            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true)
        }
        
        controller.messageComposeDelegate = self
        self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
        let impact = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator() // 1
        impact.impactOccurred()
         }
    
    

    else
    {
        print("error in sending")
    }
}
```

Code of the other Storyboard:

```
import UIKit

class SimpleVC: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var usrLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var pwdLabel: UILabel!

var usrStr: String?
var pwdStr: String?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    usrLabel.text = usrStr
    pwdLabel.text = pwdStr

}

func customInit(usrStr: String, pwdStr: String) {
    self.usrStr = usrStr
    self.pwdStr = pwdStr
}

/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
```

}

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of my `SceneDelegate.swift`, I have the following code:

```swift
struct savedString {
    var string: String = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "mystring") ?? "" {
        didSet {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(string, forKey: "mystring")
        }
    }
}
```

From there, I can load it into a View using

```
@State var myString = savedString()
```

And then use it within my view body (to set the placeholder for example)

```
Text(myString.string) // get
TextField("My String", text: $myString.string) // set
```